# SQL Find duplicates against specific records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

**Edit:** It is MS SQL Server 2008

I want to find duplicates against only specific records,
in example below I want to find duplicates against records that have `Status = 1`

Here is example data set

```
ID  |Name   |Status 
------------------------
1   |ABC    |1
2   |BAC    |1
3   |CBA    |1
4   |ABC    |2
5   |BAC    |5
6   |BAC    |7
7   |DAE    |8
8   |DAE    |2
```

What I want to get is this

```
Name    |Count  
-----------------
ABC     |2
BAC     |3
```

Originally I thought to use this

```
SELECT      Name,COUNT(*)
GROUP BY    Name
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1
```

But the result would be

```
Name    |Count  
-----------------
ABC     |2
BAC     |3
DAE     |2
```

But that's not what I need.

Comment: Don't you want CBA as well?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no CBA is not duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You want to change the `having` clause to just count values where status is 1:

```
SELECT      Name, COUNT(*)
FROM table t
GROUP BY    Name
HAVING      sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

EDIT:

If you only want things with a count greater than 1 as well as a status of 1:

```
SELECT      Name, COUNT(*)
FROM table t
GROUP BY    Name
HAVING      sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
            count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: But wouldn't I need to include Status in select clause to be able to sum them?

Comment: Courtesy of @bluefeet, you can see it work here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a953/6).  You don't need to have `status` in the `select` statement`.